# Mutex not working

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

Can please anyone let me know what went wrong with my code.
I want only one thread at a time to access the critical region but all of them enters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t th[5];
pthread_mutex_t mutex_for_some_value;
int value;

void * thread_talk(void * arguments) {

    while (1) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_for_some_value);

        printf("\n Now Accessed by %d", *((int*) arguments));

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_for_some_value);
        sleep(2);

        printf("\n\n Thread %d is left critical section", *((int*) arguments));
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int count[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    printf("\n %d", pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_for_some_value, NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\n Creating %d thread", count[i]);
        pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &thread_talk, (void*) &count[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_for_some_value);

    printf("\n Main done");

    return 0;
}
```

Now since mutex is there so no two threads should enter my critical region.
But the output is

0
 Creating 1 thread

Creating 2 thread

Creating 3 thread

Creating 4 thread

Creating 5 thread

Now Accessed by 4

Now Accessed by 3

Now Accessed by 2

Now Accessed by 1

Now Accessed by 5

Thread 4 is left critical section
 Now Accessed by 4

Thread 3 is left critical section
 Now Accessed by 3

Thread 1 is left critical section
 Now Accessed by 1

Thread 2 is left critical section
 Now Accessed by 2

Thread 5 is left critical section

Comment: The answer seems to point your problem, but anyway I'm not quite sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
sleep(2)
```

will delay the "Thread X is left critical section" output until after another thread has printed "Now Accessed by Y".  The locking should still be working.